# how to get the position of a string in a long text which is inside in a href attribute using php

Tags: php

I have an html text like :

```
$html = "<img src='http://testlink.com/something' />    
<a href='http://testlink.com'></a>
<a href='http://testlink.com/something/index.php'></a>";
```

So when I try to replace the string "http://testlink.com" from the $html with "http://example.com" I need  a result like :

```
<img src='http://testlink.com/something' />
<a href='http://example.com'></a>
<a href='http://testlink.com/something/index.php'></a>
```

which means the replace only work with the string which is inside in a href attribute and that href attribute should only contain the specified value which I want to replace .

Comment: How about `str_replace("href='http://testlink.com'","href='http://example.com'",$html)`?

Comment: You want to use PHP's DOM. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: actually I am taking all the links  inside the href attribute from $html , and looping that array for replacing the link with another appropriate link for each one , so I will not get the href= prefix with the link which i am searching to replace,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a DOM Parser such as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to search for a link with `http://testlink.com` as `href` and then replace it with `http://example.com`.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = "<img src='http://testlink.com/something' />    
<a href='http://testlink.com'></a>
<a href='http://testlink.com/something/index.php'></a>";

$dom = str_get_html($html);
$dom->find('a[href="http://testlink.com"]', 0)->href = 'http://example.com';

echo $dom;
```

**Output**:

```
<img src='http://testlink.com/something' />      <a href='http://example.com'></a>  <a href='http://testlink.com/something/index.php'></a>
```